# Prove that the planar curve obtained by projecting $\alpha$ into its osculating plane at $P$ has the same curvature at $P$ as $\alpha$.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha(s)$ be a regular curve with $\kappa\neq0$ at P, where $\kappa$ is the curvature. Prove that the planar curve obtained by projecting $\alpha(s)$ into its osculating plane at $P$ has the same curvature at $P$ as $\alpha(s)$.
(This is problem 1.2.14 in Ted Shifrin's differential geometry notes, (http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).)

The local projection onto the osculating plane is given by $(s,\frac{s^2\kappa}{2})$. However, i'm not sure if this equation holds only for when curves are parametrized by arc length.

Anyway, lets say that this projection is the correct projection for $\alpha(s)$ even though it's not stated to be parameterized by arc length.

The curvature is given by $\frac{|\alpha'(s) \times \alpha''(s)|}{\alpha'(s)}$.

Let $\gamma=(s,\frac{s^2\kappa}{2})$.

$\rightarrow$ $\gamma'=(1,s\kappa+\frac{s^2\kappa'}{2})$

$\rightarrow$ $\gamma''=(0,\kappa+s\kappa'+s\kappa'+\frac{s^2\kappa''}{2})$

$\rightarrow$ $|\gamma'|=(1^2+(sk)^2+(\frac{s^2\kappa'}{2})^2+s^3\kappa\kappa')^{1/2}$

So, if I apply the equation for curvature to $\gamma$, in theory I should get $\kappa$. Is this reasoning correct? Thanks!

Comment: Where you say that the local projection into the osculating plane is given by $\left(s, \frac{\kappa}{2}s^2 \right)$, you should actually have the parameterization
$(s + O(s^3), \frac{\kappa_0}{2}s^2 + O(s^3)$,
where $\kappa_0$ is the curvature of $s$ at $P$.  In particular, $\kappa_0$ is a constant and should not be differentiated.  This will make the rest of the computations a lot simpler.

Comment: Incidentally, this is recognizably a problem from Ted Shifrin's differential geometry notes.  I've edited to add a reference.

Comment: Okay cool. But since the parameterization is local, shouldn't we be able to ignore the higher order terms?

Comment: Yes, higher order terms can be ignored.

Comment: Okay, if $\gamma(s)=(s,\frac{ks^2}{2})$ then I got that $\gamma'(s) \times \gamma''(s)=\kappa$.

However, the denominator $|\gamma'(s)|$^3 is not behaving well... Is there a reason that $\gamma$ is arc length parameterized because $\alpha(s)$ is? Otherwise, the donominator will  be $1+3ks+3(ks)^2+(ks)^3$